# Is it possible to make the designer run a method

Tags: visual-studio, methods, windows-forms-designer

**The setup is like this:**

Imagine you need some controls to the form at which are not supported by the designer and you need to set the height and width of these controls at runtime. However you cannot compile the project because you have some missing dependencies that the project requires. Those dependencies need developer licences to run and are very expensive, so there are only one set of them and you are not the one that has them.

**Which leads to this problem:**

How can you run a method that simply adds the stuff you to the program in the designer. The method is not dynamic and is simply there to set up the user control.

**Extra Information:**

The control in question is a grid view which supports adding controls to it, and I want to see the result of adding controls to it so I can properly size the columns without making an additional project just to get the sizes right. I can modify the grid view.

**Answers welcome in both C# or VB. I use both. This project in question is in VB, but knowing how in C# is more than welcome.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suitable workaround to this problem is via a properties. What I did was add a property to this control that takes an Action of the control, while in the form that calls the control I added a static property that returns the said method, as an action.

**C#**

Custom Control

```
public Action<myControl> SetUp
{
    get { return x => { }; }
    set { value(this); }
}
```

Form

```
public static Action<myControl> SetUp
{
    get 
    {
       return x => 
          {
               /* Do Stuff */
          }; 
    }
}
```

In the Form's designer

```
this.myControl1.SetUp = myForm.SetUp
```

**VB**

Custom Control

```
Public Property SetUp() As Action(Of myControl)
{
    Get 
        Return
             Sub(x)
             End Sub
    End Get
    Set 
        value(Me)
    End Set
End Property
```

Form

```
Public Shared Property Setup() As Action(of myControl)
    Get 
       return
          Sub(x)
               'Do Stuff
          End Sub
    End Get
End Property
```

In the Form's designer

```
Me.myControl1.SetUp = myForm.SetUp
```